# QGIS: Error message in query builder

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, query, update

I am using QGIS version 2.14.1 (Essen) and trying to update data in my table using field calculator.

I am inputing the following statement:

```
update "table_1" 
set  "table_1" ='y' 
where  "table_2" ='test'
```

But I get the following error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected COLUMN_REF, expecting $end
```

Anyone know where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Are "table_1" and "table_2" from the same attribute table (same layer)?

Comment: @Joseph  yes they are from the same layer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select "table_1" for the `Update existing field` option, try using this expression:

```
if( "table_2" = 'test', 'y', "table_1")
```

Basically, you're using an `IF THEN ELSE` statement.

Comment: Perfect that works!

Comment: @philippe - Awesome, glad it works :)